Connecting AWS SageMaker Endpoint to OpenWebUI
I have recently joined this server and I’m excited to learn and share knowledge with the community. I am currently facing a few issues that I hope you can help me with.
I am using a model through AWS SageMaker, and this model has an endpoint. My main question is:
Can I connect this endpoint to OpenWebUI?
I have the necessary endpoints but I'm unable to connect them to OpenWebUI. I'm looking for detailed steps or configurations needed to link my SageMaker endpoint with OpenWebUI.
Additionally, I would like to know:

How can I achieve this connection? Are there any specific steps or configurations needed to link my SageMaker endpoint with OpenWebUI?

Has anyone here successfully done this before? If so, could you please share your experiences or any resources/guides that could help me?


I appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide. Thank you in advance!
My expecting : Can I connect this endpoint to OpenWebUI?
